# identifierForVendor vs SecureUDID / OpenID

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, udid

What is better to use instead of the old UDID? identifierForVendor or SecureUDID or OpenID?

Currently we use OpenID, but I tough that if Apple developed the identifierForVendor, it should be the best solution. From the other hand, I heard that it is problematic and will soon be deprecated as well. So what is the best alternative for the long run

When I started reading about the diferences, I encountered the SecureUDID. So maybe it is even better, since it is based on OpenUDID but is more secure. I must say, I am a little lost.

Comment: @Luda Did you mean [OpenUDID](http://www.OpenUDID.org) where you wrote [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)? If so, update your question, as OpenID is a real technology dealing with secure identity. So your typo creates confusion.

Answer (score 2):

These are my thoughts for now. Let me know what you think:

OpenUDID is not the safest method for transferring unique identifier, there are safer, like SecuredUDID. But OpenId is widely used, thus it is not likely that the app will be rejected in the app store any time soon. So there is no real need to migrate to SecureUDID.
IdentifierForVendor is not supported before iOS6, so it is not an option for apps that need to be compatible with iOS5. So in my my case, the best **for now** is to stay with OpenUDID.

Comment: I'm using BPXLUUIDHandler from BlackPixel for iOS 5 platform and the identifierForVendor for iOS6+.  This combo works pretty good without a lot of work or worry.

Comment: @John Why thous and not the others?

Comment: Honestly, I have no good answer to that question.  I looked at OpenUDID and Black Pixel replacement, and picked on out of the hat.